# Can't compile the dhcp software

Tags: makefile

I have downloaded the dhcp-4.2.3 folder from http://ftp.isc.org. During the installation, I got an error. I typed the make command and the terminal displayed this error:

```
ld: 361 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gnumake[3]: *** [sample] Error 1
gnumake[2]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I don't understand the error, and I can't things that went wrong during the make session. So could anyone help?

Comment: What OS? (Apparently only certain ones are supported in that version.) And considering the error message, can we assume you're trying to build for x86-64?

Comment: I use Mac OS X Sierra 10.13.2 and yes 64 bit

Comment: From [dhcp-4.2.3-RELNOTES](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/dhcp/4.2.3/dhcp-4.2.3-RELNOTES): "Only Solaris, Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, and OpenBSD are supported."